# What is HTHUMBNAIL in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was looking at the windows HTHUMBAIL for answers to what it meant but ended up not finding very much. I even did scoped search on msdn. My question where can I find the documentation for HTHUMBNAIL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTHUMBNAIL` is a handle to a DWM thumbnail, you can find a lot of functions using it on the msdn, depending on what you intend to do.

For example to register a thumbnail: [DwmRegisterThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or the general DWM [Thumbnail overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: A **DWM** thumbnail, specifically, not just any thumbnail.

Comment: Okay, that's what I found. I wish there was more info. Thanks.

Comment: @agent What more information do you need? You should have asked *that* question instead.

Comment: Since you specialize in Win32, here is what I want to know. So it is not a structure and we don't manipulate it, it is merely a handle that is passed around to use in the window functions?

Comment: @agentNil As most global resources, the Win32 API provides you with handles to manage them.

Comment: Yes, @agent. It is a handle. The standard Win32 naming convention is that types beginning with `H` are handles. Internally it is a structure, but that's an implementation detail. You (the programmer) just pass it back and forth to Windows API functions. All of the ones that use this type are listed in the documentation Geoffroy linked because they all relate to DWM.

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, so its an abstraction. And that is why we don't have to have much info provided to us. Thanks.

Comment: @agentNil If you haven't come across opaque handles before you must be **very** new to Windows programming, and I'm surprised you're starting with DWM thumbnails.

Comment: @JonathanPotter What are opaque handles, never heard of them? And to answer your assumption, I am kind of new to Windows programming, but not very. I can write basic programs in it.

Comment: @agentNil Opaque means you can't see into it. It's like a black box, or any other analogy you can come up with. Basically it's a value that means something to the operating system, but not to you. Practically all handles that you get back from Windows are like this. HWND, HTHUMBNAIL, HANDLE itself - they represent an object, but to your code they should just be treated as a magic value that only the OS knows how to interpret.

Comment: Which file to include to get access of HTHUMBNAIL?
Can anyone tell me?